# How to Schedule/Queue Content for Future Date Publish in PHP?

Tags: php, cron, queue, scheduled-tasks, task-queue

I have a very basic PHP script that I use to post interesting links that I find to a filterable list on my site and also to my rss feed (which feedburner then also tweets when pinged).

What I'm wondering is how hard it would be to add a 'queue' in which I could submit multiple entries at once and schedule a future time/date for each to be released?

Similar to what [Twuffer](http://twuffer.com/) does for Twitter or [Tumblr](http://tumblring.net/adding-posts-to-the-queue-in-tumblr/) and Wordpress have done for Blog Posts.

Does this require cron jobs? Perhaps with my PHP script writing another file *'drafts.txt'* if it's a future post - and a scheduled cron to check *if time/date =, then write it to the other files*?

I'm obviously a newbie with this - but I would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Here is my current little script:

```
<?php 

if($_POST['Submit']) 
{ 
$category = $_POST['category']; 
$linkurl = $_POST['linkurl']; 
$linkname = $_POST['linkname']; 
$description = $_POST['description']; 
$submittername = $_POST['submittername']; 
$submitterurl = $_POST['submitterurl']; 
$postdate = $_POST['postdate'];

// Remove slashes.
$description = stripslashes($description);

//the data for list.txt
$data = "
<li class='$category'>
    <h3><a href='$linkurl' target='_blank'>$linkname</a></h3>
    <p><b>$description</b></p> 
    <p><small>Submitted by: <a href='$submitterurl' target='_blank'>$submittername</a><i> - $postdate</i></small></p>
</li>
"; 

$filename   = "list.txt";

$fp         = fopen( $filename,"r"); 
$OldData    = fread($fp, 80000); 
fclose( $fp ); 

$New = "$data$OldData";

$fp = fopen( $filename,"w"); 
if(!$fp) die("Cannot write $filename .");
fwrite($fp, $New, 800000); 
fclose( $fp ); 

//the data for rss.php
$feeddata = "
<item>
   <title>Supplement: $linkname</title>
   <link>$linkurl</link>
   <description>$description</description>
</item>
"; 

$ffilename  = "rss.txt";

$ff         = fopen( $ffilename,"r"); 
$OldfeedData    = fread($ff, 80000); 
fclose( $ff ); 

$New = "$feeddata$OldfeedData";

$ff = fopen( $ffilename,"w"); 
if(!$ff) die("Cannot write $ffilename .");
fwrite($ff, $New, 800000); 
fclose( $ff ); 


print("<h1>Success!</h1><a href='add.php'>Add Another?</a>");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I ended up doing (thanks to Alfred for getting me thinking in the right direction):

- I added a radio buttons in my form to post "Now" or "Later".
- Selecting "Later" reveals a datepicker which passes a datetime var into my script for when I would like the article published.
- In my script, if "Now" is selected, the data is written directly to the .txt file as shown above. If "Later" is selected, the data is written (with publishing timestamp) to a MySQL db.
- I scheduled a cron job to run another php script every ten minutes to write any data with a timestamp that has passed to my .txt file and remove the entry from the db.

Works great!

Answer (score 2):

You could read more about this over [here](http://aplawrence.com/BDD/bbcronbasics.html) I guess, but a quick summary:

> Use cron to execute jobs on a regular
>   schedule (e.g., run an automatic tape
>   backup each work night or generate
>   end-of-month reports).  Use at to run
>   a job once at some time in the future.
>   Use them both to automate your
>   repetitive tasks!

I guess you should use `at` to schedule your tasks

---

But you could also have a look at Google app engine [task queue](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/)/[cron](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) to schedule your tasks for free(generous quota). It uses [webhooks](http://wiki.webhooks.org/w/page/13385124/FrontPage) to execute tasks and scales automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the help - you got me thinking in the right direction!